# Convertir un String a formato Date

Tags: javascript

Buenas estoy intentando convertir un string similar a este:

```
"200822100030"
```

a formato de fecha en JavaScript, en donde cada 2 valores son la fecha y hora con formato (d/m/y h:mm:ss) es decir:

```
// 20 = día
// 08 = mes
// 22 = año
// 10:00:30 = hora
```

Y quiero convertir ese string en formato de fecha en JavaScript.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que has intentado, mas que una pregunta parece una solicitud...

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te comentamos que debes realizar preguntas agregando información necesaria que ayude a solucionar el problema, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], si necesitas una opinión puedes realizar preguntas en [chat], saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

asumiendo que el string tenga siempre esa longitud, puedes usar el siguiente codigo para obtener tanto un string en el formato que querias como un objeto de fecha de js, dejo los dos ejemplos, saludos.

```js
var str = "200822100030";

var date_str = `${str.slice(0, 2)}/${str.slice(2, 4)}/${str.slice(4, 6)} ${str.slice(6, 8)}:${str.slice(8, 10)}:${str.slice(10, 12)}`

var date_str_iso = `${str.slice(2, 4)}/${str.slice(0, 2)}/${str.slice(4, 6)} ${str.slice(6, 8)}:${str.slice(8, 10)}:${str.slice(10, 12)}`

var date_obj = new Date(Date.parse(date_str_iso));

console.log(date_str)
console.log(date_str_iso)
console.log(date_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

En principio es fácil hacerlo con un [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), pero tiene truco el asunto, porque el manejo de fechas (y números también) es de pena en JavaScript

```js
function GetParts(fecha){
  let resp=[];
  for(let i=0; i<fecha.length; i=i+2){
    resp.push(Number(fecha.substring(i, i+2)));
  }
  return resp;
}

function GetDate(fecha){
 let p = GetParts(fecha);
 //return new Date(2000+ p[2] ,p[1] -1 ,p[0],p[3],p[4],p[5]); //de esta manera transforma la fecha a UTC-0, generando una diferencia de hora
 
 //De esta manera muestra la hora que fue seteada
 return new Date(Date.UTC(2000+ p[2] ,p[1] -1 ,p[0],p[3],p[4],p[5]));
}

console.log(GetDate("200822100030"))
```

En el ejemplo anterior te darás cuenta que hay un retorno comentado, este retorno cambia la hora por la hora UTC-0. Es decir javascript interpreta que lo ingresado es en hora local, pero los `Date` lo trabaja con hora UTC-0 así que aplica el offset correspondiente.

Esto es útil para muchos casos, pero especialmente molesto para cuando solo se requiere mostrar una fecha por pantalla

Comment: Que hace la primera funcion de getParts ?

Comment: @ImSilent Divide el string en 6 partes (dia,mes.,año,hora,min,seg) y retorna un array